# Unknown component from kitchen machine

Tags: components, identification

Yesterday (for the first time seriously) I was disassembling a broken kitchen machine. Not to repair it, but to (hopefully) get some interesting electric components.

Sadly, there was not much inside that was of much use, except some bolts and nuts. And a big AC motor which was too much attached to the machine to be reused.

However, the only interesting looking component was kind of 'exploded' only the enclosure to be in one piece. But I don't know what it is. I'm not planning to fix the machine, but just wondering what kind of component it is.

Below are pictures of the description. The pictures are overlapping mostly but this way everything is shown.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks to me like a choke, consisting of a series inductor with parallel capacitors.

Comment: Looks to me like a mains (220 V) filter, intended to block the electrical disturbances from the motor from entering the mains. These disturbances can cause noise and pops on radios and televisions. You could replace it with a similar " mains filter" but do make sure that it can handle the power, voltage and current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ... thanks ... however, I'm not planning to fix it, I just hoped to get some interesting components out of it (which I didn't succeed in). At least I know now what the component does :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says 2 * 2000pF and 220V. That means it is two 2nF capacitors for a motor running at mains voltage to reduce the electrical noise caused by the motors. That is if it has three wires. If it has more wires, then @TonyM is right and it is a choke with also inductors. I think I see a 'F' symbol for Farad, that means it also has inductors.
[ADDED] Oops, @JorenVaes is right, inductance is in Henry. Sorry, a very silly mistake by me.

They are often used with AC motors that has two carbon brushes.

These things do explode sometimes, for example in old vacuum cleaners. When no short circuit was created, the apparatus might even continue to work. It might spark more and cause more noise on a radio.

Because Europe has 230V and 240V, this component must be old, since it says rated for 220V.

Comment: F for farad -> Inductors? To my knowledge, inducance is still in measured in units of Henry

Comment: It indeed has 3 wires. I assume it were two capacitors.

Maybe I should have taken it out a bit more carefully, but also the device itself is really old (around 40-50 years). And also the switch was not working very good anymore, but I learnt something by disassembling it, and by your answers and remarks from others, so thanks!

Comment: The markings also include "1,6 MHz" and something in "M Ohms" which suggests it is an assembly of components, (probably a filter) not just a single capacitor or inductor.

Comment: @JorenVaes, thanks for the correction, I have added a [ADDED] paragraph.